# Can someone identify this part. Peugeot

Tags: part-identification, parts

For my surprise when i went under the hood to change the light bulb I've noticed that the plug melted away. Ive no idea on how to identify parts i don't know allot about motors, so i was wondering if someone know that the part number might be.

Car: Peugeot 407 2004

Picture: 
[image]

Answer (score 3):

It seems that the plug got already "repaired" by some "handyman" with a sluggish soldering job.

I doubt that the receptacle of the bulb is available separately. Perhaps you want to go to the local scrap dealer to look for a used headlight

Supposedly the was a dealership recall for the 407, the problem where the melting "H1" bulb connectors.

I, personally, would

1. Look if the recall is valid/still active for you car.
2. Replace the headlight with an after-market model or one from the scrap-yard. (After-market headlights start at about 100€ at my location, let a garage adjust the headlight inclination afterwards)

Comment: Thanks for this info! The call back isn't active anymore, replacing the entire left headlight is my only option of i cant find it at a scrapyard.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like dipped beam H1 halogen bulb and its "holder" is melted.
You probably know what type bulb is for sure from your manual. Just look for holder to it.
I think you may need to go to a repair shop or consult to a friend who is experienced in electrical work to connect it.

The reason for this is because of the corrosion in your holder. The corrosion causes resistance to current and heats up the holder and everything attached to it. You MUST replace the holder. It is inadvisable to just re-connect them back!

Comment: yes i already have a bulb to replace this one(not sure if it even needs to be replaced) but i have no clue how to identify the holder. But Ill give the manual a try hope i can find something

Comment: It is simply BULBTYPE + HOLDER. Go and do a web search for example "buy H1 car bulb holder" (assuming bulb was H1 type. You will have many options :)

Answer (score 0):

From your picture, that bulb has only 1 terminal and you can fit a crimp replacement available in any motor parts shop. The (brown probably) earth - the smaller wire also has a crimp terminal but a smaller size again easily available. You may need to sleeve (with insulation) the existing wires or cut them back and replace the damaged sections.